# How to find JavaScript variable via input value?

Tags: javascript

This is a sample from my java script code. With this code I get a correct result (1, 2). Now, instead variable "james" I want to set a variable depending on input value (var input in this case). How can I do that? Is there a way to find JavaScript variable on the page via input value?

```
 var james = "James", 
     daniel = "Daniel",
     jacob = "Jacob";

 // some code //

 var james = [1, 2],
     daniel = [3],
     jacob = [4, 5];

 function buttonclick()
 {
    var input = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var text2 = "";
    var y;
    for (y in james) {

        text2 += james[y] + "<br>"; 
        }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text2;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick them up through the `window` global object:

```
 var james = "James", 
     daniel = "Daniel",
     jacob = "Jacob";

 // some code //

 var james = [1, 2],
     daniel = [3],
     jacob = [4, 5];

 function buttonclick()
 {
    var input = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var text2 = "";
    //input could be james, daniel or jacob
    var y;
    for (y in window[input]) {

        text2 += window[input][y] + "<br>"; 
        }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text2;
 }
```

Unless they are in a closure or nested in some function.

Comment: Yes, it works! Just in for loop, instead of james[y] , I suppose you meant (window[textruta])[y]

Answer (score 0):

The same like it is done with var input in your example. But I guess you're asking to make the variable when someone actually puts something in into the input?
Then you need to make a function which listens for example to the onKeyUp event of the input field and then saves the current value into the variable.